# What is solid_air surface tension?

Tags: boundary-conditions, surface-tension

I know that the liquids in general have surface tension, but when I started reading about contact angles I got confused and started asking myself the following questions:

1. Why isn't surface tension a property of the liquid alone, but a property of the liquid's interface with another medium?
2. How is there even something called solid_air surface tension (γsa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Surface tension can be physically interpreted as the variations in the free energy arising at the interface/surface. Since the surface is normally comprised of multiple phases or components, the surface tension is, hence, a property of liquid and the medium at it's interface.
2. For a water droplet in contact with rigid solid and air, the definition of contact angle arises from the surface energies of the solid-water, solid-air and water-air. This is called as the Young-Dupre's equation ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting)). If the solid is soft, i.e., deformable, the contact angle formed at the water-solid interface would additionally depend on the softness of the solid (elasto-capillary length scale) and size of the water droplet. If the solid is as soft as liquid, the contact angle would then be determined from the Neumann's triangle ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting)). See this [reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.1654) for more details in the context of soft solid and the contact angle in soft solids.

Comment: That is really helpful thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The surface tension of a liquid *is* a basic property of the liquid alone- but since solids also possess surface energy, the nature of the solid upon which the liquid is sitting will affect the *contact angle* that the droplet of liquid assumes after it has equilibrated with the solid surface.

Think of the edge angle of a droplet on a solid surface in the presence of air as being the result of equilibration of *three* force vectors,  arising from the liquid-solid interaction, the liquid-air interaction, and the solid-air interaction.

Comment: So you are saying that the surface tension is a property of liquid but its value might change due to the liquid-solid and liquid-air interactions, and if so then why would the interaction between solid and air will ever effect the contact angle. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I mean. Have a look at the wikipedia page on this topic

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.